# Populate new row with VBA button click

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a list that adds a new row of data each time a button is clicked. I have the following code assigned to the button when clicked:

```
    PurchaseDate = InputBox("Enter Purchase Date:")
    Sheets("TrackRecord").Select
    i = 0
    Row = i + 1
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Row
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Dashboard!R26C4*(1/Dashboard!R26C12)"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Dashboard!R26C2"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = PurchaseDate
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Dashboard!R26C8 + R2C4"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Waterfall!R[8]C[5]"
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:I2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("F2:I2").Select
End Sub
```

This code works fine, but I'd like it populate the next row below instead of overwriting the same row each time the button is clicked. I know that I have to iterate through the "Range("A2").select" section, e.g. "Range("A2").select"  --> "Range("B2").select" .. But I don't know how to do this in VBA for Excel. That's why I am asking you folks ; ) .

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist the next row even when you close excel and open it again, it's better to find the last row each time.

```
 Dim Row As Long

    Row = GetNextRow(Sheets("TrackRecord"), "A") 

    PurchaseDate = InputBox("Enter Purchase Date:") 

    Sheets("TrackRecord").Select 

    Range("A" & Row).Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Row 
    Range("B" & Row).Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Dashboard!R26C4*(1/Dashboard!R26C12)" 
    Range("C" & Row).Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Dashboard!R26C2" 
    Range("D" & Row).Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = PurchaseDate 
    Range("E" & Row).Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Dashboard!R26C8 + R2C4" 
    Range("F" & Row).Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Waterfall!R[8]C[5]" 
    Range("F" & Row).Select 
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F" & Row & ":I" & Row), Type:=xlFillDefault 
    Range("F" & Row & ":I" & Row).Select 
End Sub 


Private Function GetNextRow(sheet As Worksheet, column As String) As Long

    'Look for the first empty row in the specified column

    Dim Row As Long

    For Row = 1 To 65535
        If sheet.Range(column & Row).Formula = "" Then
            GetNextRow = Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Row

End Function
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but this code doesn't solve my problem (it writes over the same row repeatedly). I think I need the variable "Row" to be persistent, so that the row number is stored after the button is clicked. As it is, the variable "i" is initialized to 0 whenever this code is run. I'm not sure how to make "Row" variable persistent. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Ah!  Here: This will now always add to the end of the sheet, by looking up column A and returning the next blank row.